# What does CONVERT(INT, N_TYPE)&128 do?

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently working through several SQL Functions someone else did and i am getting results i'm not able to explain.

The broken down part looks like this:

```
SELECT
   N_TYPE,
   CONVERT(INT, N_TYPE)&128,
   CONVERT(INT, N_TYPE)&64
FROM TBL_EXAMPLE
```

N_TYPE is a decimal(10,0) field. Some Examples of what i get returned:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|  N_TYPE   | CONVERT 128 | CONVERT 64 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|         0 |           0 |          0 |
|       200 |         128 |         64 |
|       136 |         128 |          0 |
|        32 |           0 |          0 |
| 536870912 |           0 |          0 |
|        72 |           0 |         64 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

I thought it returned 64 or 128 respectively, if N_TYPE Is above those values, but this isn't the case (as seen above at N_TYPE=136, where 64 is not returned).

So, what does this actually do?

Comment: `&` is the [bitwise AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: It's a bitwise AND

Comment: It demonstrates that you can violate all normal forms and cram multiple data items into a single column's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is converting the `N_TYPE` column to an `int`. The second part is using the 
`&` operator which is the a [bitwise AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

So if you apply `x & 64`, you will get a value of 0 if the 7th binary digit from the right is not set, or 64 if that digit is set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand (`&`) in SQL Server is the ***bit-wise*** operator for `AND`, and the way that's used on your example is to determine that the bits that compose the integer values `128` and `64` should also match in position with the bits that compose the value on the left side (the result of `CONVERT(INT, N_TYPE)`).

Check these examples:

```
Position    8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
Result                              
0           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2           0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
4           0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8           0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
16          0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
32          0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
64          0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
72          0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
128         1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
136         1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
200         1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

You will see that `200 & 128` will return (bit-wise) `10000000` which are bits that both have 1 (the `AND` works this way), and that converts back to `128` as `INT`.

Another example `136 & 8` will return `00001000` which converts back as `8`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `&` is is a bitwise operator used for bit manipulations between two expressions.

For example

```
 select 200&128
```

Will be calculated as

```
    200      11001000   
&   128      10000000
---------   ---------   
=   128      10000000
```

Similarly

```
select 31&128
```

will be calculated as

```
    31      00011111    
&   128     10000000    
---------   --------
=   0       00000000
```

You can read more about Bitwise operator [**Bitwise Operators (Transact-SQL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)